# Size and Valid annotation not working in spring mvc project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I use @Size and @valid annotation in my spring mvc project but it did not work and did not display the message which i want to display.

Comment: show us your code, configuration and other relevant details. As it currently stands the question is likely to be down voted and / or flagged for closure.

Comment: Thank you @Bond-JavaBond but i found answer after hard working.
I'm new on spring mvc and learned through tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the zip file from the link : http://hibernate.org/validator/downloads/
2. Extraxt the zip file
3. Copy all jars of folder hibernate-validator-x.x.x/dist/lib/required
   ( If **hibernate-validator-x.x.x.Final.jar** file is not present in the folder then download it and also copy this jar. )
4. Paste jars into **/WEB-INF/lib** folder in the spring mvc project.
5. Add requiered code into the spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.parth.hellocontroller"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/studentmessages"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to properties of your project
2. Go to build path and add external jar from downloaded file
3. Right click on your `@size` and `@valid` annotation and import those things 
   done